# Why can't I create a Bitmap with data from ImageAnalysis use-case with CameraX in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, image, bitmap

I am trying to create a `Bitmap` with data coming from the `ImageAnalysis` use-case from the `CameraX API`, which is in format `RGBA_8888`.

This is how I get the `byte array` within the overriden analyze method:

```java
Image image = imageProxy.getImage();
Image.Plane plane = image.getPlanes()[0];
ByteBuffer buffer = plane.getBuffer();

buffer.rewind();
byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
buffer.get(bytes);
```

Later on, I try to create a `Bitmap`  like that:

```java
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

And the result is **NULL**. According to the [Bitmap docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory#decodeByteArray(byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)), a null is returned when one tries to decode an invalid byte array.

How do I create a Bitmap or get some valid Bitmap bytes?

Comment: A null is also returned if the bitmap would become too big for available memory.

Comment: Maybe, but this can't be the case as it used to work (on the same device) with Camera1 API and I'm just trying to update it with CameraX

Comment: Are you shure the used resolution is the same?

Comment: Absolutely, but even a much lower resolution doesn't work.